# Lack of editing property and setEditing:animated: in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Unlikely UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewCell lacks of `setEditing:animated:` and the `editing` property.

Is this by design? Is Apple enforcing other best practice for handling the editing in a UICollectionView and its cells?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you need:

Subclass UICollectionViewController like `ABCCollectionViewController`:

```
let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ABCCollectionViewController())
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` of `ABCCollectionViewController`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

Then override setEditting method:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)

    // Use these methods to do the edit things, without test but should works
    collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: indexPath)
    print("editting")//Do some edit thing
    collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()  
    collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition()
    collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
}
```

Then you can call:

```
setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are changing some state like `allowsMultipleSelection` in your `UICollectionView` when editing:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = editing
}
```

You could simply add this to your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
var isEditing: Bool {
    return (superview as! UICollectionView).allowsMultipleSelection
}
```